# Invertible matrix by using polynomial in LDPC codes

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

I am studying about QC-LDPC codes.
These codes can be represented by matrices or polynomial.
For instance:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vWR4.png).
So, we have two polynomials: $a_1(x) = 1 +x$ and $a_2(x) = 1+x^2+x^4$.
The second circulant has invertible polynomial
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUbFf.png):
$a_2^{−1}(x) = x^2+x^3+x^4$.
I created these matrices and by Gaussian elimination for binary matrices, I found inverse matrix.

Hovewer, my question is: how to find exactly inverse polynomial without using matrices: how from $a_2(x) = 1+x^2+x^4$ can I get $a_2^{−1}(x) = x^2+x^3+x^4$.

Additionally, a generator matrix can be found by next way:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjvVh.png). And I have two questions: how to get $(1 + x^2)$ from $a_2^{−1}(x)∗a_1(x)$, where polynomial multiplication $(∗)$ is modulo $x^v−1$; and how to get $1+x^3$ from $(1+x^2)^T$.

Source of pictures: http://materias.fi.uba.ar/6624/index_files/outline_archivos/SJohnsonLDPCintro.pdf

Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Inverse = compositional inverse?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Because the example involves circulant $5\times5$ matrices over the field of two elements, my educated guess is that the asker wants to calculate inverses in the ring $\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^5+1)$. At least the provided example fits.

Comment: Such inverses are calculated with the extended Euclidean algorithm. The inverse exists because $\gcd(1+x^5,1+x^2+x^4)=1$. The key is that the ring of circulant matrices is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^n+1)$, $n$ the size of the matrices. Anyway, this is somewhat basic polynomial algebra and Math.SE might be a better fit.